# how to upload image to server using html file type?

Tags: java, servlets

I need to upload an image to server, I found a tutorial at http://www.tutorialspoint.com/servlets/servlets-file-uploading.htm
but the problem is that at line `List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);` my editor pop an error saying

> cast argument 'request' to 'contextrequest'

or

> change argument type 'request' to 'contextrequest`

Actual request type: `HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response`

but if I do cast it to contextrequest then i get the error saying

> java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade cannot be cast to org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.RequestContext

Can someone tell me how to fix it without changing request type or casting it

Comment: And what is your editor? You did something wrong, the [ServletFileUpload.parseRequest(HttpServletRequest)](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/servlet/ServletFileUpload.html#parseRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-) accepts `HttpServletRequest`. Perhaps you used wrong version of the commons-fileupload library?

Comment: My editor is eclipse and what library is the right one to download then?

Comment: Well, the latest (1.3.2 ATM) from http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/ should be OK. If it does not help, you need to share more about how your Eclipse project is set up.

Comment: the link you provide doesn't have no .jar file and the source or binary files says file doesn't exist on server

Comment: okay i just found that if I remote `import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.RequestContext;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;

` imports `parseRequest` gets fine, i get some other errors like `isMultipartContent`